# Compare two colums within limited number of characters and clear duplicates

Tags: excel, vba

I have three columns:

```
Client Numbers              Client Numbers Verified    Verification Status
999999999999/98989691699    999999999999               Verified
888888888888/58555555555    111111111111    
454545454545/69412999999    888888888888               Verified
22222222222/111111555555    YYYYYYYYYYYY    
888888888888/56998165446
```

I am trying to:
a) Compare Columns A & B with respect to Left 12 Characters Only and Find Duplicates
b) if Duplicate is found then Clear (Not Delete) the content in the Left 12 character, duplicate value found in Column B
c) And Input test "Verified" in column C in same row number as column A

I found many macros that compare and delete contents but none that do as I require. I tried mixing some macros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**edited** after OP's clarifications

you may try this code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim cell As Range, f As Range

    With Worksheets("Clients") '<--| reference "Clients" worksheet (change "Clients" to your actual worksheet name)
        With .Range("A1", .Cells(.rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)) '<--| reference its column "A" cells from row 1 down to last non empty one
            For Each cell In .Cells '<--| loop through referenced cells
                Set f = .Offset(, 1).Find(what:=Left(cell.Text, 12) & "*", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole) '<--| look for current cell first twelve charachters string in adjacent column cells first 12 characters content
                If Not f Is Nothing Then '<--| if any match has been found...
                    f.ClearContents '<--|... clear column "B" cell that matched the search...
                    cell.Offset(, 2).Value = "Verified" '<--|... and write "Verified" in column "C"  current cell row
                End If
            Next cell
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but is not working correctly: One it is Clearing Value in Column A instead of B and most important it is only considering 1st Matching Cell on both columns and not all.ALSO please note that it is not necessary the numbers or values in column A and B will be random and not necessary adjacent to each other.

Comment: _One_) your question was not clear to me as to what column was to be _cleared_ so I assumed it was column "A". but the change is minimal . _Most Important_) I don't get you. please explain in more detail

Comment: I ment that Values in Column A are not in Line (Adjesant) to Values in Column B.Values in Column B can be anywhere to march with calumn A.Does this clarify

Comment: ure a genius it is working as required but only a small issue.it is matching full cell value for Column B with A and not 12 Charaters for Column B.So if A has a Value 999999999999/88888585851 And B has a value 999999999999/8998925566 then it is not matching, where as it should.

Comment: And 1 More issue...Varified is coming adjesent to matching cell B where as it should come inline (adjesnt) to matching cell A